# PHP: echo number of duplicates in a table by most common

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to echo the most common duplicates in a table. I have been able to echo the name of the duplicates but what I'm looking for is a separate column in the table that shows how many times the duplicate occurs. Is there a way of echoing the COUNT(*) value? Also a way of organizing the values by size would be helpful.

My php:

```
$interests = "SELECT name, COUNT(*) FROM pageinterests WHERE pageid = '$id' GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1";
$interestresults = mysqli_query($conn, $interests);
```

My html:

```
      <div class="panel panel-default panel-table">
<div class="panel-heading">
<div class="row">
<h2 class="cba-title">Interests</h2>

                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                            <?php
                                if(mysqli_num_rows($interestresults) > 0){
                                    $rim = mysqli_num_rows($interestresults);
                                    echo "
                                     <table class = 'table table-striped table-bordered table-list'>
                                     <thead>
                                      <tr>
                                       <th>Name</th>

                                      </tr>
                                       </thead>
                                      <tbody>'";

                                    for($x = 1; $x <= $rim; $x++){
                                        $rat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($interestresults);
                                        echo "<tr>

                                            <td>".$rat['name']."</td>
                                            </tr>";

                                    }

                                    echo '</tbody>
                                        </table>
                                      </center>';
                                }else{
                                    echo " There doesn't seem to be any common interests yet";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an alias  and order by for correct count sequence

```
    $interests = "SELECT name, COUNT(*) AS my_count 
          FROM pageinterests 
          WHERE pageid = '$id' 
          GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
          ORDER BY my_count";


    .......

   for($x = 1; $x <= $rim; $x++){
       $rat = mysqli_fetch_assoc($interestresults);
       echo "<tr>

        <td>".$rat['name']."</td>
        <td>".$rat['my_count']."</td>
          </tr>";

    }
```

Comment: you missed `as` in my_count

Comment: @JigarShah  t he as is not mandatory   .. anyway thanks  .. answer  updated

Comment: No I implemented this and it still works without the as. I'll accept this answer when the time limit lets me. Thanks!

Comment: Missing the "order by" for complete answer.

Comment: @astrocrack   .correct .. asnwer  updated  with order by

Comment: Please implement a while loop instead of a for loop with a counter.   ...I'm closing a question with this page.  Perhaps order DESC.

Comment: @mickmackusa  please .. explain better your comment  .. is not clear to me

Comment: Instead of `for($x = 1; $x <= $rim; $x++){` could you more simply write a `while()` loop for the rows to be displayed?  (The duplicate that I hammered with this page is now a "Linked" post if you want to see it.)

Comment: I can  ... but this is the answer  for the question  .. .. seems strange that using the code proposed  by the OP for answer is depreacted .. .. the question  is clearly related  to a sql problem ... and the PHP  use of a kind of a loop or a another is marginal in this code  .. and anyway is not wrong ..  ..for me is better remove the php  code  ..and leave only the core of the answer

Answer (score 4):

You could use an alias like this:

```
SELECT name, COUNT() as The_Count 
FROM pageinterests
WHERE pageid = '$id'
GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT() > 1
ORDER BY The_Count DESC;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*) as mycount FROM ...
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to use an alias for count(*).Then you can use it for order and echo.

```
$interests = "SELECT name, COUNT(*) as count_alias FROM pageinterests WHERE pageid = '$id' GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ORDER BY count_alias DESC";
```